# Was the passport of one of the 9/11 terrorists found, while "nothing else" from the airplane was recovered?

Tags: united-states, 9-11

Someone who "believes branches of the U.S government planned 9/11" said that:

> The passport of one of the terrorists was "found". How is it that this
>   passport survived the crash, while nothing else of the planes' content
>   was recovered from it?

**Regarding this specific claim** : was the passport of one of the terrorists recovered? Were other objects from the plane? If the passport survived by most other objects did not, what's the explanation?

Comment: Where are you quoting from? Did they mention which site they are talking about? (Pentagon, Pennsylvania? WTC?)

Comment: [9/11 Myths](http://www.911myths.com/html/passport_recovered.html) addresses some of the issues here, but still no source of the claim.

Comment: Ah, [here we go](http://www.911myths.com/index.php/Personal_Effects_and_the_Crash-Proof_Passport). Anyone want to construct an answer from this?

Comment: @Oddthinking - I'm quoting from a friend ... if they mentioned a specific website, I don't remember it.

Comment: @Oddthinking I would think that the link you provided does the job of debunking...  Links to NTSB reports and everything that shows that the "nothing else" part is an outright lie by the conspiracy nutters.

Comment: "A man is his own easiest dupe, for what he wishes to be true he generally believes to be true" Demosthenes
It's easier for us Europeans to see the truth because we are not brainwashed by the American nationalism.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The passport of Satam al Suqami who was on American Airlines flight 11 was recovered.  From the 9-11 Commission report

> The passport was recovered by NYPD Detective Yuk H. Chin from a male passerby in a business suit, about 30 years old. The passerby left before being identified, while debris was falling from WTC 2. The tower collapsed shortly afterwards. The detective then gave the passport to the FBI on 9/11.

This is found in endnote 109 on page 40 of [this document](http://www.9-11commission.gov/staff_statements/911_TerrTrav_Ch2.pdf).

This would suggest that the passport was blown out of the building and was found on the street.

As for the claim that nothing else of the planes content was recovered:
[Photographic evidence](https://web.archive.org/web/20041027045357/http://www.pbase.com/peteburke73/image/1459719/original) of two men examining a seat cushion from flight 11.

To counter the argument that papers from the plane couldn't have survived here is [a story from the NY Times about a letter that survived](http://www.nytimes.com/2001/12/20/national/20LETT.html).

I doubt that will settle it with your friend but it might be a good place to start.  For more debunking check out [this site](http://www.skeptic.com/eskeptic/06-09-11/).

Comment: Your photographic evidence link doesn't work.

Comment: "_The passport was recovered by NYPD Detective Yuk H. Chin from a male passerby in a business suit, about 30 years old. The passerby left before being identified_" Hmmm ... Sounds like perfect fodder for some conspiracy theory.